# How to query a range of values with Fauna and FQL?

Tags: faunadb

Im' having problem with FaunaDB. I'm new to it, went through docs, but no luck. I'll jump imto showing you the code right now but SO complains that my question has too much code in it.

I'm trying to do the following SQL statement with FQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM order
  WHERE cid = '1234'
  AND fulfilled = false
  AND rank >= 0
  AND rank <= 100
```

I've tried the following:

```js
q.Paginate(
  q.Intersection(
    q.Match(
      q.Index('order_by_cid'),
      '1234',
    ),
    q.Match(
      q.Index('order_by_status'),
      false,
    ),
    q.Range(
      q.Match('order_by_rank'),
      [0],
      [100]
    ),
  )
)
```

But this returns `{ data: [] }`

My indexes:

```js
{
  ref: Index("order_by_cid"),
  ts: 1602095185756000,
  active: true,
  serialized: true,
  name: "order_by_cid",
  source: Collection("order"),
  terms: [{ field: ["data", "cid"] }],
  partitions: 1
}

{
  ref: Index("order_by_status"),
  ts: 1602163027885000,
  active: true,
  serialized: true,
  name: "order_by_status",
  source: Collection("order"),
  terms: [{ field: ["data", "fulfilled"] }],
  partitions: 1
}

{
  ref: Index("order_by_rank"),
  ts: 1602611790710000,
  active: true,
  serialized: true,
  name: "order_by_rank",
  source: Collection("order"),
  values: [{ field: ["data", "rank"] }, { field: "ref" }],
  partitions: 8
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index should be:

```
CreateIndex(
  {
    name:'refByCidFulfilled',
    source:Collection("order"),
    terms:[{field:['data','cid']},{field:['data','fulfilled']}],
    values:[{field:['data','rank']},{field:['ref']}]
  }
)
```

And you can query

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Range(
      Match('refByCidFulfilled',[1234,false]),[1],[100])),
      Lambda(['rank','ref'],Get(Var('ref')
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Luigi Servini, that works! Even though there were misplaced parenthesis in your code